# Inicializar server.js IONIC 1 para rodar em "produção"

Tags: ionic, mongodb, mac

DEVERIA O SERVER.JS SER INICIADO ASSIM QUE EU EXECUTAR ELE NO MEU CELULAR ?

Como eu poderia configurá-lo para trabalhar dessa forma?

**Isto é porque eu tenho um serviço em mongo, e ele precisa ser executar a conexão com o mongo que é implementado em server.js**

[image: Figura 1]

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte:

- No seu `package.json` procure a seção `scripts`
- Adicione esta linha (se existir substitua)

  ```
  scripts: {
      "start": "ionic serve && nodemon server.js"
      //Outros scripts aqui abaixo
  }
  ```

Ai então na raiz do seu projeto simplesmente execute `npm start`

Comment: Olá @khaosdoctor @ricardo-moraleida!

inclui o script conforme sugerido. porém quando executo o npm start, primeiramente ele executa o ionic serve. só após eu dar um quit, é que se executa o nodemon server.js.

deixei somente o nodemon server.js , funciona também. rodando só o server.js

Quando executo ionic emulate ios, a aplicação abre. mas quando clico no botão que irá fazer a conexão com o mongo simplesmente não funciona, porque parece que o server.js não foi startado

Comment: Tenta usar `&` ao invés de `&&` então ele vai executar as coisas em background.

Comment: não funcionou. lembrando que estou usando o IONIC 1

Comment: Mas você está rodando o npm start? Qual é a sequencia de comandos que você está rodando?

Comment: verdade, esqueci esse detalhe. agora executei com o npm start. aparentemente tudo certo. executou o server. não abriu nem a app no browse. com ionic emulate abriu a app, mas não conectou com o banco (não executou o server), isso porque quando executo nodemon server.js no prompt e tento autenticar, funciona.

Comment: Mas ai você tem que decidir o que você pretende com o comando, o comando que eu te passei inicia o serve do ionic (se estiver com o `&` em background, ai não abre o browser) e inicia o `server.js`. Se você quiser outros comandos do script do npm, basta criar outros scrips abaixo deste e rodar com `npm run <script>`, por exemplo `npm run serve` e no json `serve: 'ionic serve && nodemon server.js'`

Comment: me atrapalhei na hora de formular a pergunta . reformulei a pergunta. veja se podes me ajudar; @ricardo-moraleida

Comment: poxa vida, tão simples. eu que não sabia que precisa rodar isso em um servidor node como o heroku por exemplo. é preciso estruturar o projeto de maneira que o server.js (node) fique no servidor  :) , no caso eu usei o **heroku**. abraços